# Django Nose Tests Failing - Traceback from Nose Code

Tags: python, django, nose

I am unable to run django nose tests, all processes fail with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeffquinn/Code/Nuna/data-intrawebVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/multiprocess.py", line 652, in runner
    keyboardCaught, shouldStop, loaderClass, resultClass, config)
  File "/Users/jeffquinn/Code/Nuna/data-intrawebVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/multiprocess.py", line 669, in __runner
    config.plugins.begin()
  File "/Users/jeffquinn/Code/Nuna/data-intrawebVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/jeffquinn/Code/Nuna/data-intrawebVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/jeffquinn/Code/Nuna/data-intrawebVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/cover.py", line 156, in begin
    self.coverInstance.exclude('#pragma[: ]+[nN][oO] [cC][oO][vV][eE][rR]')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exclude'
```

Here are the relevant bits from `pip freeze`:

```
Django==1.5.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
South==0.7.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
boto==2.8.0
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-appconf==0.6
django-compressor==1.2
django-extensions==1.0.3
django-json-field==0.5.5
django-nose==1.1
django-storages==1.1.6
django-waffle==0.9.0
djangorestframework==2.1.17
nose==1.3.1
```

Anyone else seen this? I've seen it mentioned in this pull request (https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/pull/710) but not clear what the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

I just went into the nose source code and commented out lines 156-158.

```
    #self.coverInstance.exclude('#pragma[: ]+[nN][oO] [cC][oO][vV][eE][rR]')
    #self.coverInstance.load()
    #self.coverInstance.start()
```

All my tests run fine now. O_o